# How many different box combinations can you get?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 12 books, all different. Four of them are fiction, and eight of them are non-fiction. I want to send you a gift. I'm going to send you five books - two fiction, three non-fiction. You will get them in a big old box, all at once. How many possible gifts can you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible gifts you can receive:
$$^4C_2*^8C_3$$